# Remove CPT Slug with 2 taxonomies and 1 post meta

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I am trying to remove my CPT slug I have tried various answers on stack overflow but none seem to work for some reason.

My Code:

```
    add_filter('post_type_link', array(__CLASS__, 'rewrite_permalink'), 10, 3);

//Tell WP products can rewrtie this way
add_action( 'pre_get_posts',  array(__CLASS__, 'products_parse_request' ) );

add_action('init', array( __CLASS__, 'add_rewrite_tags'), 10, 0);


  public static function add_rewrite_tags() {
      add_rewrite_tag('%product_holiday%', '([^&]+)');
    }

    function rewrite_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
      $post = get_post($post_id);
        if ( self::$post_type != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) return $permalink;

            // Get post
            if (!$post) return $permalink;


            // Get country terms
            $countries = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, '_product_countries');
            if (!is_wp_error($countries) && !empty($countries) && is_object($countries[0])) {
              $country_slug = $countries[0]->slug;
            } else {
              $country_slug = 'country';
            }

            //Get product type
            $product_type = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, '_product_types');
            if (!is_wp_error($product_type) && !empty($product_type) && is_object($product_type[0])) {
              $product_type_slug = $product_type[0]->slug;
            } else {
             $product_type_slug = 'product-type';
            }

            //Get post holiday
            $holiday = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_event_holiday_type', true);
            if (!empty($holiday)) {
              $holiday = $holiday;
            } else {
             $holiday = 'holiday';
            }

          return strtr($permalink, array( '%product_holiday%' => $holiday, '%_product_countries%' => $country_slug, '%_product_types%' => $product_type_slug));

          //'/' . self::$post_type . '/' => '/',
    }


    function products_parse_request( $query ) {


      if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || 6 != count( $query->query ) || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) ) {
          return;
      }

      if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
          $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', self::$post_type, 'page' ) );
      }

    }

    /**
     * Register post type
     */
    private static function register_post_types() {

        $post_types = array();

        $labels = array(
          'name'                => __('Products', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
          'singular_name'       => __('Product', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
          'menu_name'           => __('Products', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
          'name_admin_bar'      => __('Product', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
          'add_new'             => __('Add New', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
          'add_new_item'        => __('Add New Product', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
          'new_item'            => __('New Product', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
          'edit_item'           => __('Edit Product', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
          'view_item'           => __('View Product', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
          'all_items'           => __('All Products', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
          'search_items'        => __('Search Products', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
          'parent_item_colon'   => __('Parent Products:', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
          'not_found'           => __('No Products found.', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
          'not_found_in_trash'  => __('No Products found in Trash.', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN)
        );

        $post_types[] =
        array(
          'post_type' => 'products',
          'args' => array(
              'labels'              => $labels,
              'public'              => true,
              'publicly_queryable'  => true,
              'show_ui'             => true,
              'show_in_menu'        => true,
              'query_var'           => true,
              // 'taxonomies' => array('_product_types', '_product_countries'),
              'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'products/%product_holiday%/%_product_countries%/%_product_types%' ),
              'capability_type'     => 'post',
              'has_archive'         => false,
              'hierarchical'        => true,
              'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-tag',
              'menu_position'       => 41,
              'supports'            => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes')
         )
        );

        foreach($post_types as $post_type) {
          register_post_type($post_type['post_type'], $post_type['args']);
        }
    }
```

This code does work for the URL structure /products/holiday/country/product-type however I need to remove /products ... If I remove it from the post type it works but then the rest of the pages on WordPress breaks so I am guessing there is something else I need to add here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it sorted in the end, needed to add a rewrite rule (see below) if you need full source code then let me know and I will be more than happy to paste it.

```
    public static function add_rewrite_rules() {
  add_rewrite_rule( '^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?post_type=products&product_holiday=$matches[1]&_product_countries=$matches[2]&_product_types=$matches[3]&name=$matches[4]', 'top' );
}
    add_action('init', array( __CLASS__, 'add_rewrite_rules') );
```

Thanks,